# Button on Popup form with few more user defined fields

Tags: acumatica

When I cilck on a button on main toolbar, I am displaying a popup form (PXSmartPanel) with few fields on it. Whenever I click on the main toolbar button, I want first the control should go to the popup form and based on buttons on popup form (Ok/Cancel), it should perform the action.
However, I tried that but eventually when I click on button on main toolbar, it first executes the code behind for that button and then shows popup.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. You can use AskExt method of your DAC class to show popup first and then execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use px:PXSmartPanel with AskExt. With help of PXSmartPanel you can customize your screen, and even add some buttons to your pop up. [Here](http://blog.zaletskyy.com/yuriy-zaletskyy-s-blog/pxsmartpanel-in-acumatica) I wrote "short" manual how to do it.